# v-img only appears in v-for loop when used with regular img HTML tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a super weird problem here, I want to use a for-loop (using `v-for`) for images inside `/static`.

Strangely, using `v-img` only works if it's used in conjunction with `img`. I'd like to strictly use `v-img` for easy formatting and continuance.

Here is my code(s) and a screenshot for each example:

### Just using `v-img`

```
<div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
 <v-img :src="image.src"></v-img>
</div>
```

Nothing is displayed.
[image]

### Just using `img`

```
<div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
  <img class="image" :src="image.src" :alt="image.alt">
</div>
```

Images are displayed with standard `img` properties.
[image]

### Using both `v-img` and `img`

```
<div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
  <v-img :src="image.src"></v-img>
  <img class="image" :src="image.src" :alt="image.alt">
</div>
```

Images are displayed from both `v-img` and `img`.
[image]

Comment: Where is `images` coming from?

Comment: @Josef7 the `images` object in `data`

Comment: Can you provide the whole code for the component? I don't have the same problem with the snippet you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I have given an example on codepen

> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVmMYK

```
<v-img v-for="image in images" :src="image.src"  aspect-ratio="2"/>
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `<v-img :src="require('image.src')"></v-img>` I hope it helps.

Comment: I got `Cannot find module 'image.src'` (NuxtServerError)